# How to disemvowel a string with a condition where if the letter "g" is right beside a vowel, it would also be considered a vowel?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

Working on a homework question where all the vowels in a string need to be removed and if the letter "g" is beside a vowel, it would also be considered a vowel. For example given the string "fragrance" I want the string returned to say "frrnc"

This is what I have so far:

```
def disemvowel(text):
    text = list(text)
    new_letters = []
    for i in text:
        if i.lower() == "a" or i.lower() == "e" or i.lower() == "i" or i.lower() == "o" or i.lower() == "u":
            pass
        else:
            new_letters.append(i)
    print (''.join(new_letters))

disemvowel('fragrance')
# frgrnc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

import re

```
def disemvowel(text):
    return re.sub(r"G?[AEIOU]+G?", "", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)


tests = {"fragrance": "frrnc", "gargden": "rgdn", "gargdenag": "rgdn", "gag": ""}

for test, value in tests.items():
    assert disemvowel(test) == value

print("PASSED")
```

Output:

```
PASSED
```

Comment: What if the g precedes the vowels?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I added the case when g precedes the vowel. Thank you.

Comment: @VladBezden  Thank you for the reply although 1 scenario does not seem like it would work with this function. If a string like "gag" was given, the output should be blank, where in this case it would print out "g". I would greatly appreciate any kind of advice for this situation.

Comment: @snk, I modified regexp to covers 'gag' case. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting, does this stack?

So if you had the word baggga, would the outer g's turn into vowels, which then would turn the inner g also into a vowel? So is the output bg or is it b?

You can either remove all g's next to vowels and then in a second step remove all vowels.

Or you could replace all g's next to vowels by, let's say 'a', and then remove all vowels. If the 'g is a vowel'-rule stacks, you may have to repeat the first step until the string does not change anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a variable to track if the previous letter was a vowel.

```
def disemvowel(text):
text = list(text)
new_letters = []
last_vowel_state=False
for i in text:
    if i.lower() == "a" or i.lower() == "e" or i.lower() == "i" or i.lower() == "o" or i.lower() == "u":
        last_vowel_state=True
        pass
    else:
        if last_vowel_state==True and i.lower()=='g':
            pass
        else:    
            new_letters.append(i)
        last_vowel_state=False


print (''.join(new_letters))
```

Input

`disemvowel('fragrance')`

Output

```
frrnc
```

Input

```
disemvowel('gargden')
```

Output

```
grgdn
```

Comment: I would also need it to work for when g is before a vowel

Comment: How would I get it the function to work if let's say a word like "gag" was given?